# MariaDB connection with Sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

I have been checking for the connectivity of MariaDB, with Sequelize.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

// Setting up database (MariaDB) connection
const sequelize = new Sequelize('dbName', 'usr', 'pass', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mariadb'
});
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
/home/lt-196/api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:236
        throw new Error('The dialect ' + this.getDialect() + ' is not supported. Supported dialects: mssql, mysql, postgres, and sqlite.');
        ^

Error: The dialect mariadb is not supported. Supported dialects: mssql, mysql, postgres, and sqlite.
    at new Sequelize (/home/lt-196/api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:236:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/lt-196/api/app.js:21:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MariaDB
For MariaDB compatibility you have to install the package mariasql@0.1.20, or higher.
The configuration needs to look like this:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  dialect: 'mariadb'
})
```

Or Try this:

MariaSQL: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mariasql

A node.js binding to MariaDB's non-blocking (MySQL-compatible) client library.

```
var Client = require('mariasql');

var c = new Client({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  user: 'foo',
  password: 'bar'
});

c.query('SHOW DATABASES', function(err, rows) {
  if (err)
    throw err;
  console.dir(rows);
});

c.end();
```

MariaSQL is recommended.

Comment: MariaSQL is working thanks, but 1st option would be better and it is not working.

Comment: You can use 'mysql' as dialect.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-connector-nodejs

NPM

```
    npm install --save mariadb
    npm install --save sequelize@next
```

Yarn

```
    yarn add mariadb
    yarn add sequelize@next
```

```
  const Sequelize = require('sequelize'),
    sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.db_name, process.env.db_user, process.env.db_pass, {
    dialect: 'mariadb',
    dialectOptions: {
      socketPath: process.env.db_socket,
      timezone: process.env.db_timezone
    },
    pool: {
      min: 0,
      max: 5,
      idle: 10000
    },
    define: {
      charset: 'utf8',
      timestamps: false
    },
    benchmark: false,
    logging: false
  })
```