# Sequelize fails to load mariadb

Tags: webpack, sequelize.js

When bundling Sequelize with webpack, mariadb fails to load.

I tried both local and global installation of mariadb module (both time the other one was uninstalled). Also tried specifying the `dialectModulePath` without any success. When debugging, I came to the point where `require(moduleId)` is called. It worked in the debug console, but the app itself crashed.

Webpack config (I use some variables for paths - bundles go into app/public/server under the project root):

```
{
    entry: [`${appDir}/src/server/index.js`],
    output: {
        filename: `bundle${[args.mode === MODE_PRODUCTION ? '-[contenthash]' : '']}.js`,
        path: outputDir,
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    },
    target: 'node',
}
```

App should be loading the mariadb module. Instead I get the following error:
`Error: Please install mariadb package manually`

Comment: is mariadb package present in your package.json file?

Comment: In the attempt where I installed it locally - yes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51653620/mariadb-connection-with-sequelize - answer is at the very bottom.