# Node - Error: The dialect mariadb is not supported. Supported dialects: mssql, mysql, postgres, and sqlite

Tags: node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

I have a node server and DB is mariadb. When I am trying to connect to DB then getting error

```
Error('The dialect ' + this.getDialect() + ' is not supported. 
Supported dialects: mssql, mysql, postgres, and sqlite.');
    ^

Error: The dialect mariadb is not supported. Supported dialects: 
mssql, mysql, postgres, and sqlite.
at new Sequelize (/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:236:15)
```

I have modules
    mariadb: ^2.1.1
    mariasql: ^0.2.6
    sequelize: ^4.37.6
    mysql2: ^1.7.0

Please let me know if anyone have idea of that

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I go the solution by updating the sequelize version to 5

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51653620/mariadb-connection-with-sequelize - scroll all the way to the bottom.